# Problem with image of text divider in Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am attempting to divide an image of a block of text into separate images of each line of text. For some reason, all I ever get is a set of black images.

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
img = Image.open("C:/Users/name/Desktop/Pytorch AI/download.png")
cut_imgs = np.zeros([200, 1000, 500])
img_data = np.array(img)
for x in range(img_data.shape[0]):
    for y in range(img_data.shape[1]):
        if img_data[x][y] > 10:
            img_data[x][y] = 100
        if img_data[x][y] <= 10:
            img_data[x][y] = 0
z = np.sum(img_data, axis=1)


c = 0
d = 0
for a in img_data:
    if z[d] != 0:
        e = 0
        for b in a:
            cut_imgs[c][d][e] = b
            e += 1
    if z[d] == 0:
        c += 1
    d += 1

    



print(cut_imgs[1])
for g in range(len(cut_imgs)):
    img1 = Image.fromarray(cut_imgs[g].astype(int))
    img1.save('C:/Users/name/Desktop/Pytorch AI/' + str(g) + ".png")
```

I'm not sure why the images are all black.
Edit: it seems as if it has something to do with numpy converting the integers in img_data into floats when put into cut_imgs. I'm not sure why it does this, but I can fix it by multiplying cut_imgs by 100.

Comment: `for a in img_data:` is not what you apparently think it is. `a` is not a index here. It is a whole row. So `a` inside the loop is a 1D-array of pixels. The reason why it doesn't crash after that, when you `for b in img_data[a]:`, is because it is legal, in numpy, to use arrays as indexes. Son `img_data[a]` is still a thing. It is an array, that you can also iterate. But it is an array of lines of image, whose line number are the values of the pixels of a line... well something that doesn't make any sense, even tho it is computable.

Comment: You were obviously trying to do `for a in range(len(img_data))`, then `for b in range(len(img_data[a])):`.

Comment: (Which is also a bad idea. One should never ever use `for` to iterates rows and columns of images. Because it is way too slow. And whole point of numpy is to provides way to do these computation by batches, so that those `for` loop are not coded in very slow python language, but in the internal code of `numpy` that is in C.  But well, even if it is a bad idea to code for loops yourself, at least, it would work, very slowly, but correctly, if you were using indexes as I said)

Comment: Note that in your code `d` is also a line number in `img_data`, and `e` would be a column number. So, I can see that you've already struggled with that, since that is quite strange to recompute those indexes. If you had just replaced `for b in img_data[a]:` by `for b in a:`, then your code may (not 100% sure, I "simulate" this mentally only) have worked. Since in fact you don't use `b` any where, (`e` is the counter you use, not `b`. For loop on b is just a way to repeat things "width" times). And you use `a` only in this `for b`...

Comment: `f` and `d` are also redundant.  So if you had used `for a in range(len(img_data)):`, `a`, `f` and `d` would have been identical all along. And then with `for b in range(len(img_data[a]))`, `b` and `e` would also have been redundant. Only `c` serves a real purpose, which makes sense, since it is neither a line nor a column number, but a "cut" index.

Comment: Unrelated note: `np.rot90(img_data, k=1, axes=(0, 1))` (and all other `np.rot90`) are void statements. It has no effect at all (except a very slight waste of cpu time, but not much, since it doesn't really move any data). You probably meant to do something like `img_data=np.rop90(img_data)`. Point is: `np.rot90` doesn't change the array in place. It returns a new array, which is the original rotated (in fact, not strictly speaking a new array, but a new view on the same array. But point is, it is returned value that is rotated, not argument)

Comment: Did you consider sharing your image if you would like some help?

Comment: @chrslg I have put a few of your ideas into practice, and simplified the code somewhat. I've edited my question above with the new code. For some reason I am still getting black images. I had a lot of issues that were essentially just typos because it has been 6 months since I coded.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is quite precisely what you might expect to see of a .png image of a paragraph of black text on a white background.

Comment: If you want folks to help you, it is generally a good idea to make it easy for them. People don't want to waste their time guessing if your image is black on white, or white on black, whether the text is anti-aliased or not, whether it is lossy JPEG or lossless PNG, why your arrays are any particular size and so on. Please read about [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark Setchell As I stated, the image is black text on a white background. From reading the code, you can tell that it is a png image. Whether the text is antialiased or not doesn't matter for the sake of this program. I am dividing the text into lines, not individual characters, and no great level of precision is needed to accomplish that. You can easily reproduce the results with any png image of black text on a white background that is smaller than 500 by 500.

Comment: But your code seems to consider that it is white text on black background. How could z be 0 otherwise ? z is the sum of all pixels in a line. To be 0, you need all pixels to be 0. That is black. So you are searching for a black line, that goes from the very left to the very right of the image, without a single non-black pixel. Quite hard to find in a black on white text.

Comment: Are you sure even `0.png` is black, btw? It should be the only subimage, and should be a grayed version of your original text. Only one subimage, since there aren't any full black line. And grayed, because you turn 255 into 100

Comment: Also, you should use `.astype(int)` to create the output image. First of all, it is ambiguous Clearly choose a `np.?int*` type. Namely, `np.uint8`, which is both what PIL expect to encode a grayscale image anyway, and also what you really need, since what you have are only integers between 0 and 10. And, worst case scenario, you are on a 64 bits machine where `int` is interpreted as `np.int64`, and then `PIL` with simply crash. Or, on previous version of PIL, it completely ignores the type any way, and just use the 1000×500 1st bytes representing whatever array you pass, and 500000 uint8.

Comment: So, you may endup with a inconsistent result.

Comment: And anyway, you should need to have to worry about that anyway. You should have allocated the array with the correct type from the start. So `np.zeros((200, 1000,500), dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: @chrslg I got so many downvotes on this question initially that my stack overflow account got suspended. Then I left for a long time. That's why I haven't been responding. I've worked a lot on other problems since then, and I think I'll be restarting this entire project from the beginning. Thanks for the help. I'll keep your advice in mind when I start working on this again. Edit: Actually, I think the question that got so many downvotes was a different one about the same project, which then got deleted. Regardless, it's why I haven't responded. This platform is too easy to manipulate and bot.